# Can we fill DataSet without DataAdapter?

Tags: asp.net, dataset, dataadapter

I know that we normally fill `DataSet`with the help of `DataAdapter`'s `Fill` method, but I want to know that Can we fill `DataSet` without `DataAdapter`?

Any idea ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `DataSet.Load` to load from an `IDataReader`.
Or `DataSet.ReadXml` to read from an Xml document.

Take a look at the `DataSet` methods on MSDN.